# Apache fatal error

Tags: php

Following fatal error we are getting in apache errorlog. So IO operation increased and log file size is increasing. We dont know how we can findout and fix it?. Anyone knows pls share the details for our references.

Recently Upgraded Version : PHP ver from 5.2.17 to 5.3.14 after upgradation only following error we are getting, previously we didnt get this issue.

[Wed Sep 05 06:41:20 2012] [error] [client 80.12.96.14] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare DomainNameInfo() (previously declared in /home/rackapps/conflg/ltnit.lg4:261) in /home/rackapps/lgconf/ltnit.lg4 on line 515, referer: http://in.mc1935.mail.yahoo.com/mc/welcome?.gx=1&.tm=1346806375&.rand=8k3tjpq0fmk8b

Note : Actually its a included files. We cant able to findout the landing php file. Because in that file we have included the above file. how we can findout the landingfile.

Comment: The error message is exactly what it says.  You're trying to declare the same class more than once, or you're including the same class file more than once.

Comment: You probably include the file which contains the function DomainNameInfo() twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare DomainNameInfo()

This is an php error and not apache. You definied a function **DomainNameInfo()** on lltnit.lg4 on line 261 and on lgconf/ltnit.lg4 line 515 you defined the same function again .... there's your fault ....

hint: when you use inlcude() / require you can alternativ use the function include_once() / require_once() to avoid the error by including functions twice ...